# Insert vector inside list

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have two pointers to containers of type `T`.

The first one `*buffer` has a fixed size (power of 2, decided by the user at run-time, 64 by default).

The second one `*big` has an unkown size, probably big (you don't say?).

When `*buffer` is totally filled, its elements are added to `*big` and `*buffer` is emptied (I still don't know if delete and reallocate it or erase each element). The process is repeated several times.

At the end of the process, `*big` must be sorted. It doesn't matter if the sorting algorithm is performed when all the elements are added to `*big`, if it's performed when with a certain frequence during its construction, or it sorted because of a "smart insertion" of `*buffer` in `*big`.

Up to know I have thought a kind of "merge-sort" algorithm

1. Implement `*buffer` as `queue<T>`. Implement `*big` as `vector<queue<T>*>`. There is any way to pre-allocate it?
2. When `*buffer` is filled, run `sort()`.
3. `big.push_back(buffer)`.
4. At the end of the process, merge each element of `*big` as in the-merge-sort algorithm: take the top one, compare with all the others, the smallest is popped from its queue and moved (can I use move which is efficient?) into the final result.

Do you think that's an efficient solution, or there could be some issue with it (of course there are)? Can you think about another (more efficient) solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still don't know if delete and reallocate it or erase each element

There is no need to reallocate.

> Implement *big as `vector<queue<T>*>`. There is any way to pre-allocate it?

Yes, vectors can be pre-allocated with the `reserve` member function. But if you don't know how big it will be, then you don't know how much to pre-allocate.

> Can you think about another (more efficient) solution?

A very *simple* and therefore good solution is to use a `std::multiset` as the big structure and skip using the buffer entirely. It has the same runtime complexity as your solution `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **std::multiset** for 'big'. It elements are stored as sorted, so you don't need to call sort manually.

For 'buffer' you can use a simple **std::vector**, and use optimized insert in std::multimap:

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

Such insert is optimized and the complexity of it is **Buffer_Size * log (Big_Size + Buffer_Size)**